# Not able to update ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates, 22.04, error-handling

So I am trying to update my ubuntu version from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. But the thing is that it always runs into an error which is as follows -

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 
'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 
If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details 
about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

Previously, it said that it had disabled all my third party repositories, So I believe that the issue is not from the PPA and I made it sure by unchecking all the repositiory boxes from "software updates and properties".

After this I did a lot of finding, but ultimately could not find the resolution of my problems.

The contents **main.log** file are:

```
2022-09-04 16:14:43,969 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-41 with 
2022-09-04 16:14:43,969 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.15.0-41
2022-09-04 16:14:43,969 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-47 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-04 16:14:44,026 INFO installing linux metapackage: linux-generic
2022-09-04 16:14:44,026 DEBUG Installing 'linux-generic' (linux metapackage may have been accidentally uninstalled)
2022-09-04 16:14:44,055 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2022-09-04 16:14:44,184 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
2022-09-04 16:24:14,085 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: evolution-data-server, gnome-control-center, libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'
2022-09-04 16:24:14,103 DEBUG abort called
2022-09-04 16:24:14,106 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-04 16:24:15,558 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-41 with 
2022-09-04 16:24:15,558 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.15.0-41
2022-09-04 16:24:15,647 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 80150
```

The contents of **apt.log** file are too many, and I will post it here if it is required.

So please help me to upgrade my ubuntu LTS to 22.04 version.

Comment: Provide the output of `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. If this ran successfully, the system should be upgradeable. If not, fix your package management first of perform a fresh install instead.

Comment: @vanadium ```sudo apt dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for parth: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.```

Comment: That looks OK, but include that information, which is relevant to the problem, in the question itself: use "edit".

Comment: `2022-09-04 16:24:14,085 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: evolution-data-server, gnome-control-center, libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'` Looks like you installed non-Ubuntu or wrong-version software on your 20.04 system that *conflicts* with those 22.04 packages. If you know what you installed, then uninstall it and try the release-upgrade again. If you don't know what you installed and just want a fast fix, then back up your data and clean-install 22.04. If you want to learn, then start looking at software you installed from those disabled sources.